# Output Raw Data inside tag

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to output an optional attribute using MVC.  I have a for loop going over payment options and I'm trying to set the selected by default if that is the options selected.

```
var selected = "";
var optionLabel = $"{ senderAccount.AccountName } / {senderAccount.Balance } {senderAccount.Currency}";
if (senderAccount.AccountId == Model.AccountId)
{
    selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
}
<option data-to="@receiverAccount.Address" value="@(senderAccount.AccountId)" @Html.Raw(selected)>
    @optionLabel
</option>
```

When I go to my view I don't see the selected string despite it being set.  I've tried:

```
@Html.Raw(selected)
@(selected)
@selected
```

None of these options seem to work. I'd prefer not to duplicate the option definition.  How can I output a raw string as an optional attribute in MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes my issue but I'd still like to know how to post raw html.  In MVC Versions after 3, if the value you post is null the attribute will optionally appear

```
string selected = null;
var optionLabel = $"{ senderAccount.AccountName } / {senderAccount.Balance } {senderAccount.Currency}";
if (senderAccount.AccountId == Model.AccountId)
{
    selected = "selected";
}
<option data-to="@receiverAccount.Address" value="@(senderAccount.AccountId)" selected="@selected">
    @optionLabel
</option>
```